# How can I extend an in-wall electrical cable?

Tags: electrical, socket, extension

I have a cable which is attached to a three way socket.
The socket is oddly placed halfway up the wall and I’d like to extend the cable by 30cm or so.

What’s the best way to do this? Is a screw down block acceptable for mains?

[image]

In addition, can I chain a second socket set onto the existing one? Eg 6 instead of 3

[image]

I’m in Sweden, so EU rules apply.

Comment: Well, if this were USA, the requirement would be to add another bit of cable, connected with wire nuts,  all connections made inside a junction box. I don't know whether your existing outlet & wiring meets code where you are to begin with, let alone adding to it.

Comment: Also:  please **PLEASE** don't  cap off wires with painter's tape!  It's not reliable insulation at all.  Cap them with wire nuts so no bare wire is showing --  and make sure the breaker for that circuit is off!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such thing as "EU rules" on fixed wiring, different countries have different rules and practices.

Comment: Yeah, I thought there might not be. Circuit is off, tape is just a reminder to others not to touch